# installed amarok through macports - no playback

Tags: macos, applications, music, audio

I installed amarok through macport. It doesn't playback the mp3's (actually it doesn't playback anything).

I looked at the console and it says among other things

`.... [0x0-0x2b02b].org.kde.amarok[35766]   com.apple.console   WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not a satisfactory answer, but at the moment, phonon seems to be non-functional when installed from MacPorts.  See https://trac.macports.org/ticket/36818 and http://mac-os-forge.2317878.n4.nabble.com/qt4-mac-and-phonon-td159474.html